# How to develop truth table for a given if-else logic in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to develop one project  which takes if-else logic as input and then generate truth table for all possible cases

for example..

```
'IF ( A  AND  B )
'THEN
 '      Stat - 1
'ELSE
'      Stat - 2
'ENDIF
```

Suppose user enter the above if-else condition the tool should generate the truth table as below

```
 A   B   Output
 1   1   1
 1   0   0
 0   0    0
 0   1    0
```

Same way any complex condition may be there. So i need input from you all, how to get  started with it and what concepts will be required.

Comment: have you tried something at least?

Comment: What are those Stat-1 and Stat-2?

Comment: Why does `A AND B` have an output of `1` for only `B`?

Comment: actually i want to develop a complete project as Auto truth table generator... so for explaining i kept example... means to say if any condition is give by user to0l will be capable of generating all possible test cases...the example given above is just foe explaining... n sorry for my bad english

Comment: I think you want to [create your own parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser).

Comment: That's not C# and thus you have to explain *very* accurately what are those sources, what is A, what is B.. To example, there can be `IF (A AND B OR C AND D)` and it is easy, but what if there will be `IF (RandomObject.RandomProperty.RandomFunction(blahblahblah, blohblohbloh) AND C == 123)`, how would truth table looks here, etc..

Comment: ok by creating parser, will i able to solve BODMAS problems... and what  strategy do i need to follow to evaluate expression if they are present in the if else condtion like  if(!(A and B))

Comment: @Sinatr  there may be condtions like that also which you mentioned in comment and condition like if(A and B) will also be there ..its completely up to user....  so i want a general process which i need to follow to start up this project... Actually i want to develop this project in C# so i mentioned it as C#

Comment: After every condition parsed and boolean terms extracted, you should start from first `if`, assign boolean values corresponding to terms in that `if` condition and assign `Don't care` for the rest and assign `Stat - 1` for these entries in the table. From now, for terms you saw in previous statements, you have values not `Don't care` and this value is the complement of values in conditions you saw. I hope my comment to be clear.